# How to import contracts in Cadence using flow.json instead of relative paths

Tags: onflow-cadence

Importing contracts using their relative path is not working atm with the last version of the cadence language server. I was wondering what would be the alternative, when developing locally, for importing other contracts. My best guess is that it should be using the [`flow.json` file](https://developers.flow.com/tools/flow-cli/configuration), defining the paths for the contracts on it, but I cannot find how to specify on my contract that I want to it to use the config file for the imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LSP and flow-cli both read the flow.json file and parse depedencies the same way.

In flow.json you specify the path to a file:

- https://github.com/findonflow/find/blob/main/flow.json#L38

In other contracst and interaction you then use the same path to import

- contract example: https://github.com/findonflow/find/blob/main/contracts/FindMarketSale.cdc#L1
- script example:https://github.com/findonflow/find/blob/main/transactions/register.cdc#L1

Hope that helps.